# How to create demo for mobile app

Tags: android, iphone, demo

I know that i can use a screen cast software to capture my display as well as my emulator. But how can i replace my mouse icon with a circle like in this video
http://www.peterfriese.de/save-a-tree-put-eclipsecon-2011-in-your-pocket/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use [SimFinger](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/SimFinger.shtml) for my iPhone promotional videos

Comment: More appropriate links would be the author's blog and the official GitHub repository : http://blog.atebits.com/2009/03/not-your-average-iphone-screencast/ https://github.com/atebits/SimFinger

Answer (score 0):

This feature is entirely dependent on the screencasting software you choose. I believe Camtasia Studio does it (commercial software). There is also [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) which is free and claims to support mouse highlighting, but I've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

I used [iSimulate](http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/) for this purpose. I think that is what they used in your example, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create a demo of your app for promotion, sharing, or feedback a couple of good options are available for iOS and Android.

For android you have appsurfer.com (I'm part of the team). For iOs users, you have pieceable.com and app.io

You can create embedable widgets of your apps and put them on blogs, product pages etc.